# Firefox title bar ignoring Gnome global dark theme after upgrading to UbuntuGnome 16.10

Tags: gnome, firefox, gtk

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition as I was when using UbuntuGnome 16.04.
It respected the global dark theme and the title bar was dark.

Now due to a new hard drive, I have freshly installed UbuntuGnome 16.10 and turned on the global dark theme. All other applications and windows are respecting this setting and have dark title bars except for Firefox!

I assume this is a bug but in the meantime where can I manually change the colours?

Thanks!

Comment: Except for Firefox or Firefox dev edition? Please specify.

Comment: This is happening for me as well on dev edition (54.0a2).

Comment: This is also happening for me for both firefox and the firefox dev edition on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug indeed: ["Title bar is using the light theme when the dark theme is selected on GNOME 3.22"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1305431)

I haven't found a way to change it manually but you can use the [GTK Dark Theme Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-gtk-dark-theme/), which "make the window decorator dark to match Firefox's dark theme".